# How to get data from database between two dates using inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two table i.e. `jobs` and `company` and the format is mention below:

table1 `jobs`

```
company_name    job_title            category       job_posted_date
============    =================   ===========     ===============
ibm             xamarin developer   it jobs         26-09-2018
tech mahindra   php developer       it jobs         27-09-2018
milkyway        java developer      it jobs         15-08-2018
```

table2 `company`

```
company_name    company_logo         
============    ============         
ibm             logo_ibm.png 
tech mahindra   logo_tech.png
milkyway        logo_milkyway.png
```

and my query is:

```
SELECT company.company_logo, post_jobs.company_name, jobs.job_title, jobs.job_posted_date 
FROM company 
INNER JOIN jobs 
on jobs.company_name = company.company_name 
WHERE jobs.category = 'it Jobs' and (jobs.job_posted_date between '01-09-2018' and '01-10-2018') 
ORDER BY jobs.job_posted_date desc
```

When I hit this query and find data between `01-09-2018` to `01-10-2018` it show nothing to me where data lies between in two dates. So How can I fix this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: where is you job.category field? Can you please put that filed with value also in the table

Comment: What is the type of the `job_posted_date` column?

Comment: MySQL's date format is YYYY-MM-DD, so queries should use that too (there may be some setting value to change it though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see an issue with your `job_posted_date` column.  Perhaps you are storing text dates there.  Assuming not, and it is a bona fide date column, you may try this query:

```
SELECT
    c.company_logo,
    j.company_name,
    j.job_title,
    j.job_posted_date
FROM company c
INNER JOIN jobs j
    ON j.company_name = c.company_name
WHERE
    j.category = 'it Jobs' AND
    j.job_posted_date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
ORDER BY
    j.job_posted_date DESC;
```

Note that I compare to valid MySQL date literals such as `'2018-09-01`'.  The format you were using won't work.

If the `job_posted_date` column actually is storying *text* dates in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, then you'll have to make use of `STR_TO_DATE` to convert them first:

```
SELECT
    c.company_logo,
    j.company_name,
    j.job_title,
    j.job_posted_date
FROM company c
INNER JOIN jobs j
    ON j.company_name = c.company_name
WHERE
    j.category = 'it Jobs' AND
    STR_TO_DATE(j.job_posted_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
ORDER BY
    j.job_posted_date DESC;
```

The moral of the story here is to always use a proper date column when storing date information in MySQL.  And always compare valid date/time literals against those columns.

Answer (score 0):

You were making mistake in the date format.In your query date format must be same as it is saved in database i.e. (YYYY-MM-DD),So according to that new query is given below:

```
SELECT company.company_logo, jobs.company_name, jobs.job_title, jobs.job_posted_date 
FROM company 
INNER JOIN jobs 
on jobs.company_name = company.company_name 
WHERE jobs.category = 'it Jobs' and (jobs.job_posted_date between '2018-09-01' and '2018-10-01') 
ORDER BY jobs.job_posted_date desc
```

The Output of the query is also here in the screenshot attached.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2SWb.png